# User account not loading after installation

Tags: 14.04, login, login-screen

I installed MySql server and workbench on Ubuntu 14.04.

After some time the system hanged and after restarting it,
the administrator account is not loading.

When I enter the correct password the screen goes back the login page.

The guest login doesn't have any such problems though.

Can somebody please help?

Answer (score 0):

some times your desktop may not load due to problem with `lightdm`.

press CTRL + ALT + F4 then login using your username and password

```
sudo apt-get purge lightdm
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install lightdm
dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
```

Now  type `sudo shutdown -r now` to restart.

Comment: I tried that..but lightdm is not getting installed.Error is: Unable to fetch some archives.Run  sudo apt-get update or try with --fix-missing

Comment: comment the error please